# Issue with jaxb moxy when using binder to unmarshal xml with namespace

Tags: jaxb, xml-namespaces, moxy, unmarshalling

I m using jaxb moxy to unmarshal a xml from binder but it gives exception:A descriptor with default root element beans was not found in the project. im also using package-info.java to specify namespace.

Xml file to unmarshal-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.example.org/package">
</beans>
```

Beans.java-

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.example.org/package")
public class Beans {

String name = "ss";

@XmlElement
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.example.org/package",
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.jaxb.test;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Main class-

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        File xml = new File(
                "D:\\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2\beans.xml");
        Document document = db.parse(xml);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Beans.class);



        Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();

        Beans customer = (Beans)   jc.createBinder().unmarshal(document);//throws exception

     //Beans customer = (Beans) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);This works
    //Beans customer = (Beans) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(document);Throws same exception
```

Exception-

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-   ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element beans was not found in the project]
at  org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1014)
at  org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:199)
at com.jaxb.test.JaxbTest.main(JaxbTest.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `DocumentBuilderFactory` is not namespace aware.  This means the document you are passing to MOXy will not be namespace qualified as expected.  You can fix this by adding the following to your code:

```java
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved It.Instead of using a package-info.java i used bindins.xml .

beans-bindings.xml-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://www.example.org/package">
    <xml-ns prefix="" namespace-uri="http://www.example.org/package" />
</xml-schema>

<java-types>
    <java-type name="Beans">
    <xml-root-element name="beans"/>
        <java-attributes>

        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
</java-types>
```